# Simplest way to redirect outgoing tcp traffic to another ip in windows

Tags: windows, tcp, proxy, ip

I currently have an .exe program that talks to its server located in certain IP.

I need windows to redirect the traffic made by the application to my own machine.

99.99.99.99:4560(server) -> 127.0.0.1:4560(my machine)

Editing the hosts file will not work as there is no url and the .exe has a hardcoded ip.
I also configured a netsh portproxy but it will only redirect traffic that has my machine as destiny and not my outgoing packets.
I found some freeware from the early 2000s but with broken download links or lost forever (rinetd).

forgot to mention: http traffic

Answer (score 0):

Try adding additional address to NIC (the one you need)